# Regex help in java validations

Tags: java, regex

Hi i want to do some validations.I used to put regex in JS but im new to regex in java, so i tried to make up a code on similar lines in java.
Here is what i did.
1)Check whether first character in string is alphanumeric.
2)Check whether the string atleast 1 number.

so i wrote a code, but it is always returning false.I am not sure if i'm doing this correctly.

```
 private static boolean checkEmbeddedPassword(final String field) {
            boolean returnValue=true;


            String testpatternAlpha="/^[A-Za-z0-9].+$/";


            String testNumber="/[0-9]/";
            Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(testpatternAlpha);
            Pattern pattern2=Pattern.compile(testNumber);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(field);
            Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(field);
            boolean firstChar=matcher.matches();
            boolean numberFlag=matcher2.matches();
            System.out.println("-----the value of pwd iss-----"+field);
            System.out.println("---------Regex---------Out--put-----"+firstChar);
            System.out.println("---------Regex---------Out- for numeral-put-----"+numberFlag);
            if(firstChar){
                returnValue=false;
            }
            else if(field.contains(" "))
            {
                System.out.println("-----------cannot have space------");
                returnValue=false;
            }
            else if(numberFlag)
            {
                returnValue=false;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
```

Comment: Did you try without the beginning and trailing slashes? As far as I remember, you don't need them...

Comment: And for `testNumber = "[0-9]"`, you should use `matcher.find()` method instead of `matcher.matches()`

Comment: `Pattern.compile(...)` is an expensive method, you should initialize it in the class not at each method invocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `/` prefix and suffix in Java:

```
String testpatternAlpha="^[A-Za-z0-9].+$";
```

Also in your situation you'll want to be using `Matcher.find` rather than `Matcher.matches`. You can read why in the API documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: `Matcher.find()` is only required in the 2nd regex. First one would work with `Matcher.matches()`

Answer (score 3):

we do not use `/` on the beginning and end of the regex in java.

try this...

```
String testpatternAlpha="^[A-Za-z0-9].+$"; //  first character in string is alphanumeric

String testNumber="[0-9]"; //test single number
```